# Hosted a Flask app on tornado but it does not scales the number of requests

Tags: multithreading, flask, tornado

I want to run a flask app on tornado server and scale the number of requests it handles. I found similar code as bellow on flasks deployment documentation. But when I am running this and testing for load using jmeter I found it is not scaling at all. If I used it for 5 users and sleep time was of 5 seconds in flask then it was taking 25  seconds to complete tells it is serving one request at a time. Secondly I am not getting why tornado is removed from flasks deployment documentation from version .11.x while it was present in .10.x ([reference link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/)). One more suggestion if someone could help me finding the best server for my flask app where my requirements are as follows: I have almost 40 flask apps, which I have to host. Machine config: 8 cores with 16 gb RAM. I am expecting a maximum of 100 users at a time on a particular flask app. One of my flask app takes almost 2 seconds to finish off a job.

```
from flask import Flask
import time
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/flask')
def hello_world():
    time.sleep( 5 )
    return 'Hello World'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from flasky import app

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(12000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: There's a [warning in the docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer) that's more than clear - `running a WSGI app with Tornado’s WSGIContainer is less scalable than running the same app in a multi-threaded WSGI server like gunicorn or uwsgi`.

Comment: Agreed but I thought that it would scale it a bit at least, because there it is written less scalable and not that it won't scale at all. So I thought I am going wrong somewhere in my code. Anyways I am using GUNICORN now with gevent workers and its giving good response. Thanks .